# In a Noetherian domain, what can one say if all non-zero non-units are in all but finitely many maximal right ideals?

Tags: noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) Noetherian domain. Clearly, units of $R$ are not in any maximal right ideal, and elements of $J$, the Jacobson radical, are in all maximal right ideals. All other elements of $R$ lie in at least one, but not all, maximal right ideals.

Let us say that an element $c \in R$ is almost in $J$ if $c$ is not in only finitely many maximal right ideals.

For a certain class of Noetherian domains, I think I have proved that all non-units are almost in $J$. However, before getting too excited about this, I have two questions: Are results like this already known in the literature? If so, I'd welcome references. Secondly, are there interesting consequences of this condition? It feels as if it would be close to results concerning rings that have only finitely many maximal right ideals, or rings with factorization properties.